# How to select second parameter from fetchall() in pyodbc

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am new in python so in the pyodbc. Maybe my question is very simple but I could not find any answer refer to my question.
I'm using this select

```
cursor.execute("SELECT [something] FROM [someone] WHERE [user_name]='John'")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print row.something
```

It prints some parameters for example 4 or 5.How to print only second or only third parameter.
I also used `cursor.fetchmany()` but I'm having same problem

Comment: Yes this will do, Thanks. Is there something similar to put it in the for statment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wan't just the 4th row you can do:

```
rows = cursor.fetchall()
print rows[3].something
```

But it's better if you do it in the SQL query and avoid fetching all the rows from the database:

```
SELECT [something] FROM [someone] WHERE [user_name]='John' LIMIT 1 OFFSET 3
```

[Example](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/451.cfm).

Comment: Thanks but I need all the rows and send them separatly

Comment: @DitoOgiashvili Again, not sure if I understand the question :) If you need all the rows, you shouldn't use the `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` you should fetch all of them and access them using `rows[index]` as in the first example. If you need just a subset (for example just the rows 4, 5 and 7) then I would again suggest using something like `LIMIT 4 OFFSET 3` which will fetch the rows 4, 5, 6 and 7 and then you can index them. It's not perfect, but it's better than fetching all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your mean field and not parameter

```
cursor.execute("SELECT [something] FROM [someone] WHERE [user_name]='John'")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
from row in rows:
    print row[1]
```

Comment: No its the same to print row.something